# Excel Formulas for Nth or Last Specified Weekday of Month

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dayofweek, weekday

If someone has a better solutions please let me know, but this is what I came up with to calculate the first, last, and Nth specified weekdays for a given month/year.

Cell B3: dropdown values for First, Second, Third, Fourth, Last
Cell C3: dropdown values for Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday
Cell A6 = Year (4 digit integer)
Cell B6 = Month (integer)

```
Cell B2: =IF(B3="First",1,IF(B3="Second",2,IF(B3="Third",3,IF(B3="Fourth",4,5))))

Cell C2: =IF(C3="Sunday",16,IF(C3="Monday",17,IF(C3="Tuesday",11,IF(C3="Wednesday",12,IF(C3="Thursday",13,IF(C3="Friday",14,15))))))<br>

Cell C6: =IF(B2<5,DATE(A6,B6,B2*7+1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A6,B6,B2*7-1),C2),EOMONTH(DATE(A6,B6,1),0)-MOD(WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A6,B6,1),0)+5,C2),7))
```

Cell C2 drives the seleted weekday: 11(Tuesday), 12(Wed), 13(Thr), 14(Fri), 15(Sat), 16(Sun), 17(Monday)

I also calculate first and last day of the month with this code:

```
=DATE(A6,B6,1)
=EOMONTH(DATE(A6,B6,1),0)
```

Thank for any feedback.

Comment: This is better for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I mean if it works - then how should 'better' be judged? in terms of length? number of embedded function? calculation speed/memory usage? robustness in dealing with erroneous / unexpeccted inputs (in which case a simple 'iferror' wrap would answer the - um.. 'question' you've flagged here).... Sure, sure -no doubt there will be a gazillion other ways to calcuate this  - but, I guess, 'what the previous commenter said' ☺